# Save images in database after lazy loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, lazy-loading

In my app I am using lazy loading approach to load images in `UITableviewCell` and `UIScrollView` subviews. The problem is that when app is closed and relaunched it again starts loading. Is it possible to save these images once loaded. If so, how can i do this.

I am using `AsyncImageView`.

My code is...

```
   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    AsyncImageView *imageView = [[AsyncImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 88, 88)];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    imageView.tag = 99;
    [cell addSubview:imageView];
    cell.indentationWidth = 88.0;
    cell.indentationLevel = 1.0;
    AsyncImageView *imageView = (AsyncImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:99];
    [[AsyncImageLoader sharedLoader] cancelLoadingImagesForTarget:imageView];
    NSURL *imagUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:counter]];
    imageView.imageURL = imagUrl;
```

Comment: Try [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) it will cache your image.

Comment: It's perfect for me. Thanks chinttu and keep helping all.

Comment: It's perfect for all not only for you . :)

Comment: Yes it is. But depends upon scenario.